# How remove default free spaces between UIBarButtonItems on toolbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitoolbar

How remove default free spaces between UIBarButtonItems on toolbar ?
You can see free space in screen

[image: Here is free space]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a single custom `UIBarButtonItem`. Use the `initWithCustomView:` initializer of the `UIBarButtonItem` class to create an item with both buttons in it. Create your own `UIView` subclass, a custom `UIView` with both buttons in it, or use a `UISegmentedControl` as the custom view directly.